# setState isn't setting my array to the state and I don't know why

Tags: reactjs

EDIT: I created another react app and started over and it worked

I just started learning React and I was following alone to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9eMGE7QtTk) tutorial when react gave me an error saying "movie is not defined". So I did some console logging and found out that `setMovies(data.Search);` is not actually setting the array to the useState.

```
function App() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    searchMovies("superman");
  }, []);

  const searchMovies = async (title) => {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}&s=${title}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data.Search);
    setMovies(data.Search);
    console.log(movies);
  };  

  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <h1>MovieLand</h1>
      <div className='search'>
        <input placeholder='Search for movies' value="Superman" onChange={() => { }} />
        <img src={SearchIcon} alt="search" onClick={() => { }} />
      </div>

      {
        movies?.length > 0
          ? (
            <div className='container'>
              {
                movies.map((movie) => {
                  <MovieCard movie={movie} />
                })
              }
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className='empty'>
              <h2>No movies found</h2>
            </div>
          )
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

The console.log(data.Search) grabs the array of movies from the api just fine but when I try console.log(movies) it doesn't show the movies but instead gives me an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

setState work asynchronous so when you console.log your state after setState, your console.log will log your initialState. Try to console.log outside the function.

Comment: Outside the function call and inside the useEffect callback function right?

Comment: you can call it in useEffect like useEffect(()=>{console.log(movies)},[movies])

Answer (score 1):

As @NgheMinh mentioned useState is asynchronous and you have to console.log inside a useEffect.

But the actual issue in your code is you have to returned the JSX component from the map function.

```js
<div className='container'>
  {
    movies.map((movie) => {
      return <MovieCard movie={movie} />
    })
  }
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```js
setMovies(prev=>[...prev, data.Search])
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I tried
setMovies([...data.Search])
and it didn't work either